# How to invoke an extension for UIButton in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, invoke, ibaction, viewdidload

I am still new to Swift and programming in general. I am currently stuck on how to make an extension on a button self trigger(invoke) in `viewDidLoad`. my code works when I tap the button but I want this do self trigger without tapping in `viewDidLoad`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var blinkButton: UIButton!



// Yellow Colour Error: All paths through this function will call itself

@IBAction func blinkButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
       blinkButtonTapped(blinkButton)
    }



// Yellow Colour Error: All paths through this function will call itself

extension UIButton {

    func blinkButton(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.blinkButton( nil )
        let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        flash.duration = 0.5
        flash.fromValue = 1
        flash.toValue = 0.1
        flash.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        flash.autoreverses = true
        flash.repeatCount = 100000000

        layer.add(flash, forKey: nil)


    }
```

I want to call `blinkButton` function in `ViewDidLoad`.

Comment: Why do you call `blinkButtonTapped` inside `blinkButtonTapped`? Why do you call `blinkButton` inside `blinkButton`? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass value as `nil`, because parameter has optional type or you can pass any object type.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
       blinkButton(nil) 
}
```

And you need to remove in `self.blinkButton(nil)` in  `func blinkButton`, it's called two time.

Comment: Ok. this was helpful: so I did remove the self.blinkButton(nil) from the func blinkButton..... then I rather passed this under my IBAction:  sender.blinkButton(blinkButton) and blinkButtonTapped(blinkButton) in viewDidLoad and it works just perfectly the way I wanted!